# (IEnumerable)BindingListCollectionView as Enumerable<>. How this to do?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, collections, filter

I have a problem with the filtering of the database.
For start I have downloaded this project and included its algorithm to my solution. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering

Discrepancy in the different of the ItemsSource. In the test project there are test data and in my project there is data base.
See to the screenshot

[image]

As You can see that I haven't the correct collection. for me as junior developer using this class BindingListCollectionView seems incredibly useless:)

Main Question: How I can get the correctly collection as test data. 
Or something another way.. I don't know how it done..

```
    IEnumerable collection = ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    var result = collection.AsQueryable().Where(query.FilterString,   query.QueryParameters.ToArray<object>());
    filteredCollection = result.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Thanks.

My wpf code and columns of the database

[image]

Comment: can you post the complete line where you are getting exception?

Comment: Yes. Done. But exception in collection.AsQueryable(). Can't conver to this Type

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like

```
(ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<object>).Cast<YourDTO>().ToList();
```

Comment: `var result = (collection as System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object>).Cast<object>().ToList().AsQueryable().Where(query.FilterString, query.QueryParameters.ToArray<object>());`

Exception: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source